# Laravel - foreach on collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreach, collections

I have a request :

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('replyComments:id,post_id,user_id,content,created_at,reply_comment_id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

When i try to echo this with a foreach, i have :

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment;
};
```

Result :
`{"id":383825,"post_id":553304,"user_id":6,"content":"test","created_at":"2022-04-28 15:16:19","reply_comment_id":null,"reply_comments":[{"id":383826,"post_id":553304,"user_id":6,"content":"reply test","created_at":"2022-04-28 16:20:16","reply_comment_id":383825}]}`

But if i do :

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->replyComments; /* or $comment->reply_comments; */
};
```

The result is `NULL`

How could i echo reply_comments ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT FOR MORE DETAILS :**

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('likes','replyComments')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get(['id','post_id','user_id','content','created_at','reply_comment_id']);

    foreach($comments as $comment){
        dd($comment);
    }
```

[image]

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('likes','replyComments')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get(['id','post_id','user_id','content','created_at','reply_comment_id']);

    foreach($comments as $comment){
        dd($comment->likes);
    }
```

[image]

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('likes','replyComments')->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->get(['id','post_id','user_id','content','created_at','reply_comment_id']);

    foreach($comments as $comment){
        dd($comment->replyComments);
    }
```

[image]

About likes and replyComments, in Comment.php :

```
public function replyComments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'reply_comment_id', 'id');
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\CommentLike::class, 'comment_id', 'id');
}
```

Comment: if this code in your controller then try to use  dd( $comment->reply_comments)  if in view try to use {{ dd( $comment->reply_comments) }} and check what  return

Comment: It's in controller and dd($comment->reply_comments); return null too :/

Comment: try to do this $comments = $post->comments()->with('replyComments')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();

Comment: make with for all data inside  replyComments

Comment: to see if the error from this with syntax or not

Comment: I edit my question with screenshots for more details :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the replies in one level like Youtube does, you need using the following query:

```
$post = Post::with('comments.replyComments')->find($id);
$comments = $post->comments;
$replies = $comments->replyComments;
```

Comment: `Exception
Property [replyComments] does not exist on this collection instance.`

replyComments is a relation : 
`public function replyComments(){ return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'reply_comment_id', 'id'); }`

Comment: Since it's a relation and we add it into our querry, it suppose to be in the collection. What do you see when you ```dd($post)```

Comment: dd($post) is good, with "comments" in relations with 3 items/comments. 
dd($comments) is good too, with 3 items.  One of comment/item add relations with 1 item/comment in replyComments, 2 others add relations with 0 items in replyComments.
dd($replies) error "Property [replyComments] does not exist on this collection instance."

Comment: I edit my question with screenshots for more details :)

Comment: It's very strange. I don't see any issue that may cause the problem. It might be a good time to start trying some stupid things like renaming the relation, creating a different relation with the same structure, getting the whole data instead of picking some of them inside the ->get() function. I don't know.

Comment: Okay... so... it's a stupid problem solve. I replaced all replyComments with replies, and it's work. I don't understand O_o But thanks a lot ! Very very much !

Answer (score 0):

reply_comments OR replyComments are not present in the output JSON.
Hope you missed it on fetching!

```
$comments = $post->comments()->with('replyComments:replyComments')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

This needs to add to the fetch code.

then

```
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    echo $comment->replyComments;
};
```

Or else you can use array.

```
displayData = [];
foreach ($comments as $comment) {
    displayData[] = $comment->replyComments;
};
echo displayData;
```

Comment: There isn't "replyComments" column, it is a function that returns comments having "reply_comment_id" as parent

Comment: public function replyComments()
{
   return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'reply_comment_id', 'id');
}

Comment: I edit my question with screenshots for more details :)

Answer (score 0):

use `print_r($comment->replyComments)` instead of echo.

Comment: I `print_r($comment->replyComments)`, `var_dump($comment->replyComments)`, `dd($comment->replyComments)` ... Same thing : NULL

Comment: I edit my question with screenshots for more details :)

Comment: You should also [add a description to your code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/979052), as explaining what it does will help OP and others learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
`$comment->replyComments` is an array and you should put it in foreach:


 foreach($comment->replyComments as $item){
     echo $item;
 }
```

or write:

```
echo $comment->replyComments[0];
```